# Recursive method for Linked Lists

Tags: java, recursion

I have a question about a recursive function that I have written. The function is supposed to return the sum of all the even entries in the list. The code, along with the helper recurisve method, is given below.

```
public int sumEven() {

return sumEven(head);
}


private int sumEven(IntListNode n) {
    int nodeNumber=1;
    int count=0;
    if(n==null){
        return count;
    }
    else if(nodeNumber%2==0 && n.getNext()==null){
        return n.getValue();
    }
    else if(nodeNumber%2!=0 && n.getNext()==null){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(nodeNumber%2==0 &&(n.getNext()).getNext()==null){
        return n.getValue();
    }
    else{
        nodeNumber++;
        if(nodeNumber%2==0){
            count+=n.getValue();
            return count+ sumEven(n.getNext());
        }
        else{
            return count + sumEven(n.getNext());
        }


    }


}
```

I am unsure as to whether I can use the nodeNumber and count in the way that I have done in the function. Each time sumEven is called, isn't the nodeNumber and the count being set back to zero. If so, then this method can't possibly work right? How else can I keep track of the count and increasing nodeNumber then?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Do use parameters instead of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));
    System.out.printf("Sum of %s is: %s\n", list, sumOfEvenNumbers(list.iterator()));
}

private static int sumOfEvenNumbers(Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return 0;
    Integer value = iterator.next();
    return sumOfEvenNumbers(iterator) + (value % 2 == 0 ? value : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple pseudo-code which you can finish:

```
int findSum(nodeptr temp, int count, int sum)
{
    if(temp==NULL)  // this indicates end of list. Return the sum until now
       return sum;
    count++;   //increment count:number of nodes encountered
    if(count%2==0)  //if it is even node, add the contents of the node
    {            
        sum += temp->value;
    }
    return findSum(temp->next, count, sum); //recursively call the function on subsequent nodes
}
```

Call the function from your main code as follows

```
res = findsum(myList, 0, 0);
```

I have followed the C/C++ convention. Change it appropriately.
This is pretty simple to understand. The key idea is to **pass updated values as method parameters** rather than using local variables.